# Issue with Google Cloud Pub/Sub and background functions invocation

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I am using few Google cloud solutions for a project:

- Google app engine (Go 1.11)
- Google cloud functions (Go 1.11)
- Google cloud Pub/Sub (Topic name : workers)

My App Engine project is simply about publishing messages to a topic "workers".

My Cloud function should be triggered when Pub/Sub receive a message on the "workers" topic.

After running some intensive load tests, I can see that not all of my workers are invoked.

The test was about to throw a batch of 200 messages every 15 seconds to reach a total of 100 000 published message (should be the same amount of function invocations) at the end.

No issues to send messages to the topic, but when i looked into the Google Stackdriver Metrics explorer (Metrics based on Execution status of the cloud function) i can see that some workers invocations are missing.

App Engine code that publish messages:

```
func PublishMessage(task *models.Task) error {
    if task == nil {
       return errors.New("Empty task")
    }

    pubSubTopic := GetPubSubClient().Topic("workers")
    ctx := context.Background()

    message, err := json.Marshal(task); if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    result := pubSubTopic.Publish(ctx, &pubsub.Message{
        Data: message,
    })

    id, err := result.Get(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    log.Printf("Published a message; msg ID: %v\n", id)

    return nil
}
```

Here is the code on my Google cloud function :

```
func Run(ctx context.Context, m PubSubMessage) error {

    task := &models.Task{}

    if err := json.Unmarshal(m.Data, task); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    log.Printf(*task.Name)

    return nil
}
```

**EDIT 1:**

Here is how i deploy my cloud function :

`gcloud functions deploy my_worker --runtime go111 --entry-point Run --trigger-topic workers`

Here is the Metrics explorer for the pub/sub :

[image: Pub/Sub Metrics]

Here is the Metrics explorer for the cloud function invocation count :
[image: Cloud function metrics]

Comment: How are you deploying your cloud function? Not sure why this is happening yet but just want to know more about your setup.

Comment: Can you share an example of logs where you see missing events?

Comment: @kingkupps Here is how i deploy my function : gcloud functions deploy my_worker --runtime go111 --entry-point Run --trigger-topic workers

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere i've edited my question

Comment: I would like to get more information to help you. You said you looked at metrics from Cloud Functions. Have you also looked at Cloud Pub/Sub metrics? You might have messages waiting to be delivered in the subscription’s backlog.

Comment: @JasonGanetsky yes i did watch at both, i added a graph related to pub/sub, howerver i looked at the metrics "num_undelivered_messages" which seems to be very high (51,228 unaknowledge messages) so i don't really know how to interpret that metric

Comment: Did you see some unexpected error code in Function or in PubSub logs?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I didn't see anything wrong on both except if i'm watching at the wrong metric but i dont see that much options to look at

Comment: By looking to your graph, I see that the orange graph is just bellow the 100 line. In addition the execution count is bellow 100 000. But it's the execution OK. Have you other status code? Anyway, sometime, for extracting better insight from logs, I perform a sink into bigquery and I try to understand thanks to query.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere i don't have other status name, i tried to use this metric on another project and while using the execution status, code should be broken down by different type on the graph such as "ok", "connection error" and "crash", unfortunately on this one i only have the "ok" status. I'll try to put the logs in a sink as you suggested

Comment: @IlièsM Can you include a screenshot of the num_undelivered_messages metric for your subscriber that you mentioned? A non-zero value for that would indicate that there are messages enqueued that have not yet been acknowledged. You might want to read [monitoring your backlog](http://cloud/pubsub/docs/monitoring#monitoring_the_backlog) and [monitoring your push subscription](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/monitoring#monitoring_push_subscriptions). You might want to look at your [Cloud Functions quotas](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas) and make sure you are not exceeding them.